# How does @Required annotation work with JavaConfig?

Tags: spring, annotations, required

I'm pretty new to the Spring Framework and I got problems to understand the `@Required` annotation in combination with a Java configured application.

Here is an example.

**Config-File**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Movie movieA() {
        return new Movie();
    }

    @Bean
    public MovieHolder holder() {
        return new MovieHolder();
    }
}
```

**MovieHolder.java**

```
public class MovieHolder {

    private Movie movie;

    public Movie getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    @Required
    public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }
}
```

**Context initialization**

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
MovieHolder holder = (MovieHolder) context.getBean("holder");
System.out.println("movie: " + holder.getMovie());
```

As far as I understood the documentation of the `@Required` annotation, there should rise an exception, because movie isn't set directly or by autowiring. Instead is the output `movie: null`.

What am I doing wrong? Or isn't this the correct use of the `@Required` annotation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the required properties in the beans that you are instantiating is your own responsibility. The [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp) that processes the bean-definitions in the classes annotated with `@Configuration` is called [`ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.html). The [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp) that processes your `@Required` annotation defaults to [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html), which is registered by default when you use  `context:annotation-config` and `context:component-scan` in your configuration. If you are not using these two tags, you can even register your own [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) as a `bean`.

Now, the default implementation of the [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) has a method called `boolean shouldSkip(..)` that checks for a boolean attribute named [`SKIP_REQUIRED_CHECK_ATTRIBUTE`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html#SKIP_REQUIRED_CHECK_ATTRIBUTE). The value of this attribute is checked for each bean during the post-processing by the [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). If it returns `false`, the `@Required` constraint is enforced, otherwise it is not.

Now, the [`ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.html) set the value of this attribute to `true` while creating the bean definitions from the `@Configuration` classes (I guess for the reason that if *you* are defining a bean, *you* should ensure that it has the required properties). Hence, the `@Required` is not enforced for such beans.

As an aside, You might think that where did this [`SKIP_REQUIRED_CHECK_ATTRIBUTE`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html#SKIP_REQUIRED_CHECK_ATTRIBUTE) attribute come from and where is it set: it is set on the instances of [`BeanDefinition`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html) that are used by Spring internally for bean creation and post-processing.

If you really want to enforce the `@Required` constraints, you would have to override the [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html), override the `boolean shouldSkip(..)` method and register this class instead of the default [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). And as the documentation for [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) says:

> A default RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will be registered by the "context:annotation-config" and "context:component-scan" XML tags. Remove or turn off the default annotation configuration there if you intend to specify a custom RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean definition.

Another way would be to use the `initMethod` attribute on your `@Bean` annotation. Which could perform checks to see that the required properties are indeed set. However, since this is code based configuration, you could just as well call that `init` method yourself.

Also, in my opinion, there is not much point in going through a lot of trouble to use your own [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html), as the following documentation says:

> Please note that an 'init' method may still need to implemented (and may still be desirable), because all that this class does is enforce that a 'required' property has actually been configured with a value. It does not check anything else... In particular, it does not check that a configured value is not null.

**So, to summarize:** `@Required` doesn't work with `@Configuration` classes by default. If you need to make sure that all your properties are set, you can just as well do it yourself when you create the bean in the `@Bean` methods (By calling some `init` method that performs such validations, or just supplying the required properties yourself). And if you *really* need to make the `@Required` annotation work, you'd need to use your own implementation of the [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html), register it as a bean in the spring context and give up the benefits of `context:annotation-config`.

Comment: Well, thanks for your solution, I will give it a try. But I don't understand why this is so complicated? Are there any reasons to not use the `@Required`-Annotation while using configurations defined in Java?

Comment: Use it if you _really need_ to. There are caveats to it (losing the benefits of `context:annotation-config`) and there is not much benefit to using it anyway. It's not very complicated though. The official documentation helps a lot, and if that doesn't work, you can just browse the source-code. You might probably using the `@Required` to ensure that some property has a valid value, and that's not what the `@Required` annotation is doing. If you need to do that, just check for it in your `@Bean` method or implement an `initMethod` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: It is not the point, that I necessarily need the `@Required`-Tag. I'm just still suprised, that this tag is always ignored, when using javabased Configuration. In `ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader` I've found following line: `beanDef.setAttribute(RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.SKIP_REQUIRED_CHECK_ATTRIBUTE, Boolean.TRUE);` which is the reason why the required check is alwas skipped.

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer says. It is not very surprising considering that the bean-creation is being carried out by you. It kinda makes sense. If you need to ensure something, just do so while creating the bean. Edited the answer though, I put in `false` instead of `true` in one place.

Comment: Ah, okay. Now it is obvious to me, what you meant by that. - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to declare a *@Bean RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor* with overridden *shouldSkip()* method.

Yes, it checks my beans, but it fails even if I set all the required properties, i.e. it always fails.
I think Spring has a real problem with supporting *@Required* annotation for Java Config, since Spring has no way to tell whether or not you have set the property when you do it directly in Java code. (It can't inspect for 'null' fields later, since this would mean changing the semantics of the *@Required* annotation which should allow explicitly set null values).

When you use an XML config, Spring creates a wrapper object to set the properties, so it can track all the configured 'setXxx()' operations.

**Conclusion**: there is no reasonable way to enable *@Required* annotation for beans created in Java *@Configuration* classes. 
(Very unfortunate feature, in my opinion, since the bean class writer and the class user might be different persons).