# Why @Required Annotation using JavaConfig doesn't throw an error if required value is not set

Tags: java, spring

This is what I have so far.

My Student class:

```
public class Student {
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Required
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The BeanDefination class:

```
@Configuration

public class BeanDefination
 {
    @Bean
    public Student student() {
        Student s = new Student();
        // s.setName("Shiva");
        return s;
    }
}
```

And the Client with the TestDemo class:

```
public class TestDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext factory = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        factory.register(BeanDefination.class);
        factory.refresh();
        Student student = (Student) factory.getBean(Student.class);
        System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
}
```

So what is wrong here that I don't get an error if the required value is not set?

Comment: Have a look here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769360/how-does-required-annotation-work-with-javaconfig)