# What is the use of RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor in Spring framework?

Tags: spring

I am a beginner in Spring framework. I have started learning Spring framework a couple of weeks. I did not get any proper explanation of RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. Please, someone, help me by giving some example of RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and where to use this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can get an idea from this  [HowToDoInJava](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/spring-required-annotation-and-requiredannotationbeanpostprocessor-example/)

Comment: see also- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769360/how-does-required-annotation-work-with-javaconfig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) is a not common used annotation in applications that use Spring.
The `@Autowired` annotation that provides both the autowiring and the requiring (by default enabled) behaviors is often preferred to.

---

[`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) is a `BeanPostProcessor` implementation.

The `BeanPostProcessor` interface defines callback methods that you can implement to provide your own (or override the container’s default) instantiation logic, dependency-resolution logic, and so forth.

In the case of `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, it enforces required JavaBean properties to have been configured.
Required bean properties are detected through a Java 5 annotation: by default, the Spring's `Required` annotation.

To be short, it allows to ensure that a bean that declares 'required' properties has actually been configured with values.  Note that the value may be `null`.

For example suppose this model class :

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

     @Required
     public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

If `setBar()` is never invoked during the initialization of the bean, a `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException` is thrown.

For example this bean configuration will trigger the exception throwing :

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public Foo getFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Of course if you add `@Autowired` to setBar() with a resolvable dependency, it will be fine :

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    @Autowired
    @Required
    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

So we could consider that a good use case for `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is a case where you don't want/cannot specify the autowiring in the class of the bean.

Note also that [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) provides also an additional feature that is according to the javadoc its primary goal :

> The motivation for the existence of this BeanPostProcessor is to allow
>   developers to annotate the setter properties of their own classes with
>   an arbitrary JDK 1.5 annotation to indicate that the container must
>   check for the configuration of a dependency injected value.

It means that you may specify another annotation that `@Required` to indicate the required constraint.
`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` defines indeed a `setRequiredAnnotationType()` method that you can override to set the annotation to use.

---

As you can see, the use of `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is related to very specific corner cases.  That's why you probably don't find many examples about it.