# Spring annotation @Required not working (no xml used)

Tags: spring, annotations

I have seen that when I put @Required in the College.java, I am not getting an exception and the code is running fine. That's not the expected behavior. Please help me.

```
@Component
public class College {


    public String s;

    @Required
    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }




@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public College collegeBean()
    {
        return new College();
    } 

    @Bean
    public Principal principalBean()
    {
        return new Principal();
    } 

}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    System.out.println("file loaded");
    College coll = context.getBean("collegeBean",College.class);
    System.out.println(coll.toString());
}
```

Comment: which spring version are you using ? [@Required](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html) is deprecated as of 5.1

Comment: 4.2 version I am using

Answer (score 0):

Why `@Required` annotation is not working is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16773655/4214241)

To make your application work , you need to annotate the `@Configuration` class with `@ComponentScan`. If the beans to be auto-detected are not in the default scope of [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) you will need to use the attributes accordingly.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfig {..}
```

Notes

1. `College` class is already annotated with `@Component` and `@ComponentScan` will detect the bean. You don't need the method `collegeBean()` in `ApplicationConfig`
2. A `String` bean will have to be available to honour the dependency. You may declare a bean in the `ApplicationConfig` for the same.

Hope this helps.